# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="news_content_container">
    @Html.Action("_AddImagesToNews", "PostImages")
</div>
```

**_AddImagesToNews.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("_AddImagesToNews", "PostImages", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_post_images" }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Id", (int)ViewBag.newsId)
        <div class="editor-label">
            <input type="file" name="Files" id="Files" multiple="multiple" />
        </div>

        <div class="submit-field">
            <input type="submit" value="Ekle" class="button_gray_small" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="images_content_container">
    @Html.Partial("_PostImages", Model.ToList())
</div>
```

**_PostImages.schtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<NewsCMS.DAL.EDM.PostImages>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <img src="~/@(item.MiddleImageUrl)" alt="@(item.Posts.Title)" />
}
```

**controller actions**

```
public ActionResult _AddImagesToNews(int Id)
{
    using (NewsCMSEntities entity = new NewsCMSEntities())
    {
        ViewBag.newsId = Id;
        return PartialView(entity.PostImages.Where(x => x.PostId == Id).ToList());
    }
}
```

When view is loading, I get error as title. I cant find the reason. If I write `@Model.Count()` in **_PostImages.cshtml** it shows the correct value with no error.

What am I missing?

Thanks...

Comment: I notice that child action (post) _AddImagesToNews returns _PostImages partial. I've never tried it, but sounds suspicious. Try renaming the post action method to  _PostImages

Comment: please include the section of your db **operations**

Comment: I m sorry I get error when view loading, not after post. Problem is in  HttpGet method.

Comment: I see, add your db operations part. It's probably there.

Comment: I get error before posting. I mean first loading. HttpPost method is never triggered. because view is never load.

Comment: does PostImages have a child entity called posts?

Comment: Yes. one-to-many relations. one post - many images

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Bear with me. Try my suggested answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see. Try this

```
return PartialView(entity.PostImages.include("Posts").Where(x => x.PostId == Id).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I passed the model like following.

```
var images = entity.PostImages.Where(x => x.PostId == Id).ToList();
return PartialView(images);
```

Also, thanks for all replays, especialy @DaveA...

I think, I should allways use this way.

Comment: I wonder how it caused the problem.

As far as I know the 'images' value is evaluated before passing it to the view, so the ObjectContext is not needed after the evaluation.

Comment: @DaveA, your suggestion works, too and yours is the more elegant. If you write it again, I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

when passing an entity in the view the context is disposed as the scope is finished
and in the view you are accessing an object via `item.Posts.Title` which can only be accessed through the context. as for displaying `title` additional data about the `Posts` would have to be retrived

using `Model.Count()` Is correct because it does not need to retrieve more data after .ToList() is done and can compute the number of members in the lis locally

Comment: Thanks for replay. I've already know this, but how can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused when concrete object is missing and '.ToList()' is required, but in the given code its not the case.

If you are using data retrieved from database in Layout or in other Partial Views make sure they are concrete objects (by using .ToList()).

You should try using IntelliTrace to see where exactly the exception was thrown (It might be in somewhere else).

Comment: but he IS using tolist() :(